# What happens if I can't see a space within 10 feet for the purposes of Blink?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light

The *blink* spell states:

> At the start of you next turn, and when the spell ends if you are on the Ethereal Plane, you return to an unoccupied space of your choice that you can see within 10 feet of the space you vanished from.

If you are blinded (or your vision to the 10 foot radius sphere around your disappearing point is blocked) before the start of your next turn, what happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The spell does not say, but you should probably appear in a random space

#### The spell does not say, therefore it is a DM call

> you return to an unoccupied space of your choice that you can see within 10 feet of the space you vanished from.

The spell does not say what happens if, when it is time for you to return to the material plane, you are blinded and cannot see. This automatically makes this a situation where the DM will have to decide the result.

#### Using the random mechanic already in the spell

If a DM was looking for an easy solution to this lack of edge-case coverage, a good one can be found already in the spell description.

The spell *does* describe what happens when there are no unoccupied spaces within 10 feet of the space you vanished from.

> If no unoccupied space is available within that range, you appear in the nearest unoccupied space (**chosen at random** if more than one space is equally near).

Using this same principle, it would make sense to require the player to return to a random unoccupied space within 10 feet of the space you vanished from. Since they cannot see, they cannot choose (or must choose randomly) a space to return in.

If they are both blind and all the squares within 10 feet are occupied they simply follow the rules as stated and return to a random spot.